# Razor Pages Model Binding List of objects with broken index

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding, razor-pages

I'm basically having a form where i'm adding and deleting items and binding them to a list using Model-Binding. This works fine with modifying fields and adding new items, but when i try to delete them i'm breaking the index and the list that is binded doesn't include all items.

The markup i'm generating looks something like that:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <input type="text" name="devices[0].id"  value="8574" />
            <input type="text" name="devices[0].type"  value="Type1" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="text" name="devices[1].id"  value="4385" />
            <input type="text" name="devices[1].type"  value="Type2" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="text" name="devices[2].id"  value="9486" />
            <input type="text" name="devices[2].type"  value="Type1" />
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my model binding like this:

```
public IActionResult OnPostSave(List<Device> devices){
    // ... do something
}
```

now i'm letting the user manipulate the Form data by simply deleting rows from the table via javascript and then sending the updated form to my `OnPostSave()`. Now when for example the row with Id "4385" is deleted, all items after that row won't get binded. Regarding to this [post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) from Scott Hanselman this absolutely makes sense, but i'm wondering if there's a work around for this? Preferably without modifying the form in js before posting it to the server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-sequential indexes are supported by the model binder. You have to use an explicit index, which is denoted by a hidden field called `propertyname.Index` for each item in the collection. I'll use the device key value from your example to illustrate, but the index value can be anything, including strings, guids etc:

```
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="devices.Index" value="8574" />
        <input type="text" name="devices[8574].id"  value="8574" />
        <input type="text" name="devices[8574].type"  value="Type1" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="devices.Index" value="4385" />
        <input type="text" name="devices[4385].id"  value="4385" />
        <input type="text" name="devices[4385].type"  value="Type2" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="devices.Index" value="9486" />
        <input type="text" name="devices[9486].id"  value="9486" />
        <input type="text" name="devices[9486].type"  value="Type1" />
    </tr>
```

You can read more about binding to collections using sequential and non-sequential indexes here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

Comment: Thank you Mike! My devices have a guid so i used this one as the index and it works like a charm! :)